# Why do I need these lifetime but not others, how to know the correct signature and how can I identify the parameters needing lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime

This is my first bit of Rust code. I added the lifetime parameters to the inner function only because the compiler told me to. Although I understand the lifetime explanation in the Rust book, I couldn't have written this signature by myself.

```
fn transform_the_expression() {
    fn create_formula<'t>(formula: & mut HashMap<& str, &'t str>, input: &'t str, re: Regex)->std::borrow::Cow<'t, str>{
        let replacement = re.find(input).unwrap();
        formula.insert("1", replacement.as_str());
        let rest = re.replace(input, "1");
        return rest;
    }

    let input = "(a+(b*c))";
    use regex::Regex;
    let re = Regex::new(r"\([\w\d][/*+-^][\w\d]\)").unwrap();
    use std::collections::HashMap;
    let mut formula = HashMap::new();

    let result = create_formula(&mut formula, input, re);

    println!("result = {:?}", result);

}
```

- Why do I need lifetimes at these 3 places in the signature?
- Why don't I need them at the other places?
- How I would go about writing the correct signature without the compiler telling me what to do?
- How can I identify the parameters needing lifetimes?

Comment: This type of question is not really appropriate for Stack Overflow. It would be better for the [Rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust), the [users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/), or [IRC](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/community.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler's great at telling you when you need to specify lifetimes, but not necessarily so good at letting you know which ones.

First of all, it's worth mentioning that there *are* lifetimes on every reference; it's just that there are [lifetime elision rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325690/lifetime-elision) which say how the compiler will fill them in if you don't specify them.

Back to your signature:

```
fn create_formula(formula: & mut HashMap<& str, &str>, input: &str, re: Regex)->std::borrow::Cow<_, str>
```

The first lifetime definitely needed is the one in `Cow<_, str>`; you need to have a lifetime to put into there to declare the function.  There are two choices: declare one, or use `'static`.  In this case, the `Cow` may point at part of the `input` parameter, so you need to tie them together.  First the new lifetime needs declaring by adding `<'t>` (any name would do) after the function name, and then using it for `input` and the return type:

```
fn create_formula<'t>(formula: & mut HashMap<& str, &str>, input: &'t str, re: Regex)->std::borrow::Cow<'t, str>
```

And finally you're putting borrowed parts of `input` into the `HashMap`.  If the `input` lifetime (which we've now named `'t`) isn't tied to the `HashMap` value, someone could pass in a hash map which lives longer than the input, leading to dangling pointers in the map.  So we need to constrain it too, giving the final version:

```
fn create_formula<'t>(formula: & mut HashMap<&str, &'t str>, input: &'t str, re: Regex)->std::borrow::Cow<'t, str>
```

The key thing is that function signatures need to convince the compiler that all the uses of references are safe, and that often means you have to be explicit about the relationships between different reference parameters (and lifetime-parametric types) when the default (via the elision rules) don't say the right thing.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped a lot.