# Adding unrelated generic parameter triggers strange lifetime error

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a trait and I want to implement it for all types that implement `std::ops::Index`. This code works (as I would expect):

```
use std::ops::Index;
use std::fmt::Display;


trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self, i: usize) -> &Display;
}

impl<C> Foo for C 
where
    C: Index<usize>,
    C::Output: Display + Sized,
{
    fn foo(&self, i: usize) -> &Display {
        &self[i]
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a5c2059cd6d7b1d84ef1b76e286f01d8&version=stable&mode=debug))

**However**, once I introduce a generic parameter to my trait, I get a strange lifetime error. This is the code ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=362ebb2fd1bdecbf87cab225d6770931&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
trait Foo<T> {
    fn foo(&self, i: T) -> &Display;
}

impl<C, T> Foo<T> for C 
where
    C: Index<T>,
    C::Output: Display + Sized,
{
    fn foo(&self, i: T) -> &Display {
        &self[i]
    }
}
```

And the strange error (apparently it's one error repeated three times in slightly different versions):

```
  error[E0311]: the associated type `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         &self[i]
   |         ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound for `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output`
note: the associated type `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 14:5...
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 | /     fn foo(&self, i: T) -> &Display {
15 | |         &self[i]
16 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that the type `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output` is not borrowed for too long
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         &self[i]
   |         ^^^^^^^^

error[E0311]: the associated type `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         &self[i]
   |         ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound for `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output`
note: the associated type `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 14:5...
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 | /     fn foo(&self, i: T) -> &Display {
15 | |         &self[i]
16 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that the type `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:15:9
   |
15 |         &self[i]
   |         ^^^^^^^^

error[E0311]: the associated type `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:10
   |
15 |         &self[i]
   |          ^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound for `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output`
note: the associated type `<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 14:5...
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 | /     fn foo(&self, i: T) -> &Display {
15 | |         &self[i]
16 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that the reference type `&<C as std::ops::Index<T>>::Output` does not outlive the data it points at
  --> src/main.rs:15:10
   |
15 |         &self[i]
   |          ^^^^^^^
```

I don't understand the error at all. Especially since the error talks about the lifetime of `C::Output` which (as I understand it) has *nothing* to do with the additional parameter `K`.

Interestingly, not returning the trait object `&Display`, but adding an associated type to `Foo` which is returned, makes the lifetime error go away ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=420a7b7f0ba85bf1d779e798a8fd1b3e&version=stable&mode=debug)). However, this is not a solution for me.

---

**What does this error mean? Does it make sense? Is it a compiler bug? What does the parameter `K` has to do with the lifetime of `C::Output`?**

Comment: Note: with feature(nll) there will be less errors. Success? ;)

Comment: Interestingly, adding the `T: 'static` condition (`impl<C, T: 'static> Foo<T> for C where ...`) fixes all errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes sense, and is not a compiler bug, but it is somewhat inconvenient.

### Full Explanation

It's possible to implement `Index<T>` for a type `C` such that `C::Output` has a type that must outlive some lifetime that is *internal* to `T`. Here's a silly example:

```
struct IntRef<'a>(&'a i32);

impl<'a, 'b: 'a> Index<IntRef<'a>> for IntRef<'b> {
    type Output = IntRef<'a>;
    fn index(&self, _: IntRef<'a>) -> &Self::Output {
        self
    }
}
```

The blanket `impl` would try to implement `Foo<IntRef<'a>>` for `IntRef<'b>`, which is unsound. To understand why, take a look at this non-compiling example:

```
let b = 2i32; // 'b begins here:
let b_ref = IntRef(&b);
let o: &Display;  // a reference that outlives 'a but not 'b
{
    let a = 1i32; // 'a begins here:
    let a_ref = IntRef(&a);

    o = &b_ref[a_ref]; // <-- this errors: "a doesn't live long enough"
                       //     which is correct!
    o = b_ref.foo(a_ref); // <-- this wouldn't error, because the returned
                          //     value is `&'x (Display + 'x)` where 'x is
                          //     the lifetime of `b_ref`
}
println!("{:?}", o);
```

`o = &b_ref[a_ref];` will not compile because `Index` is implemented such that `b_ref[a_ref]` cannot outlive `a_ref`. But `o = b_ref.foo(a_ref)` *must* compile, since the definition of `Foo<T>::foo`...

```
fn foo(&self, i: T) -> &Display                   // what you wrote
fn foo<'a>(&'a self, i: T) -> &'a ('a + Display)  // what the compiler inferred
```

... enforces that the lifetime of the output depends *only* on the lifetime of `&self` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40325690/3650362)). The compiler rejects the blanket implementation of `Foo` because if it were allowed, you could use it to "enlarge" a lifetime like that of `a_ref` in the above example.

(I couldn't come up with a way to make `IntRef` practical, but the fact remains that you *could* do it. Possibly, with internal mutability, a sufficiently clever person could introduce unsoundness were this allowed.)

---

### Solution 0: Quick & dirty

Just require that `T` never contain any (non-`'static`) references and your job is done.

```
impl<C, T> Foo<T> for C
where
    T: 'static,
    C: Index<T>,
    C::Output: Display + Sized,
```

This is probably the case for most common uses of the `Index` trait, but if you want to be able to implement `Foo<&T>` (which is not unreasonable), you'll want to try something a little less restrictive.

Another possibility is requiring `C::Output` to be `'static`, but this is again more conservative than necessary.

### Solution 1: The Best Way

Let's go back to the desugaring of `Foo::foo`:

```
fn foo<'a>(&'a self, i: T) -> &'a ('a + Display)
```

Notice the two `'a`s in `&'a ('a + Display)`. Although they are the same, they represent different things: the (maximum) lifetime of the reference being returned, and the (maximum) lifetime of any references contained inside the thing that is being referenced.

In `Index`, which is what we're using to implement `Foo`, the lifetime of the reference being returned is always connected to the borrow of `&self`. But `Self::Output` may contain other references with different (possibly shorter) lifetimes, which is the whole problem. So what we'd really like to write is...

```
fn foo(&self, i: T) -> &('a + Display)            // what you write
fn foo<'b>(&'b self, i: T) -> &'b ('a + Display)  // what the compiler infers
```

... which decouples the lifetime of `&self` from any lifetimes that could be internal to `Self::Output`.

Of course the problem now is that `'a` isn't defined in the trait anywhere, so we have to add it as a parameter:

```
trait Foo<'a, T> {
    fn foo(&self, i: T) -> &('a + Display);
}
```

Now you can tell Rust that `C::Output` must outlive `'a` for the `impl` to apply, and all will be fine ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ff0ce578450aed64453424cb06476eed&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
impl<'a, C, T> Foo<'a, T> for C
where
    C: Index<T>,
    C::Output: 'a + Display + Sized,
{
    fn foo(&self, i: T) -> &('a + Display) {
        &self[i]
    }
}
```

### Solution 2: Put the bound on the method

Solution 1 requires you to add a lifetime parameter to `Foo`, which might be undesirable. Another possibility is to add a `where` clause to `foo` that requires `T` to outlive the returned `&Display`.

```
trait Foo<T> {
    fn foo<'a>(&'a self, i: T) -> &'a Display where T: 'a;
}
```

It's a bit clunky, but effectively it lets you move the requirement to the function rather than the trait itself. The disadvantage is that this *also* precludes certain implementations of `Foo` by insisting that the return value never outlive any reference in `T`.