# Why do I get a borrow error when returning result of a child structure's method?

Tags: rust

I have structure that contains another structure and which calls a method of said child structure. But when I call this method, I receive a borrow error.

If I change the return type from `&str` to `String` it's working fine, but I want return a static `str`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d55790840097869f819f99ff0b6c7196)

```rust
struct Child {
    v: Option<i32>,
}

impl Child {
    fn get_value(&self) -> Result<i32, &str> {
        match self.v {
            Some(v) => Ok(v),
            None => Err("Values is undefined")
        }
    }
}

struct Parent {
    child: Option<Child>,
}

impl Parent {
    fn get_child_value(&self) -> Result<i32, &str> {
        return match self.child {
            Some(child) => child.get_value(),
            None => Err("Child is undefined")
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let ch = Child{v: Some(2)};
    let parent = Parent{child: Some(ch)};
    parent.get_child_value();
}
```

Error message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:20:22
   |
20 |         return match self.child {
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      cannot move out of borrowed content
   |                      help: consider borrowing here: `&self.child`
21 |             Some(child) => child.get_value(),
   |                  ----- data moved here
   |
note: move occurs because `child` has type `Child`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  --> src/main.rs:21:18
   |
21 |             Some(child) => child.get_value(),
   |                  ^^^^^

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `child`
  --> src/main.rs:21:28
   |
21 |             Some(child) => child.get_value(),
   |                            -----^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                            |
   |                            returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                            `child` is borrowed here
```

Comment: Hm, no i don't think so. It is seems like a other problem not a like i mine. Maybe i mistake, i don't sure exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things:

- If you want to return a "static `str`" as you said, change `&str` to `&'static str`. Otherwise the compiler assumes that the `str` is borrowed from `self`. This is due to "lifetime elision"; see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325690/what-is-lifetime-elision-in-very-simple-terms) for example.
- `match self.child { Some(child) => /* ... */ }` tries to move the `self.child` field which is not possible because `self` itself is borrowed. The idiomatic/modern way of dealing with this is simply saying `match &self.child` (notice the `&`). The `Some(ref child)` way is the old way of dealing with this.
- The `return` in `get_child_value` is not needed: the `match` expression is the last expression in the function and automatically returns.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: you need use `Some(ref child)` instead of `Some(child)` because the `Some(child)` takes the borrow of a child.